# Deleting labels in Prometheus

Tags: label, monitoring, prometheus

I'm using Prometheus to do some monitoring but I can't seem to find a way to delete labels I no longer want. I tried using the `DELETE /api/v1/series` endpoint but it doesn't remove it from the dropdown list on the main Prometheus Graph page. Is there a way to remove them from the dropdown without restarting from scratch?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens to me also, try to include the metric name when querying for labels' values like this:

```
    label_values(node_load1, instance)
```

ref: http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/prometheus/

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus doesn't provide the ability to delete particular labels, because this may result to duplicate time series with identical labelsets. For example, suppose Prometheus contains the following time series:

```
http_requests_total{instance="host1",job="foobar"}
http_requests_total{instance="host2",job="foobar"}
```

If `instance` label is removed, then these two time series will become identical:

```
http_requests_total{job="foobar"}
http_requests_total{job="foobar"}
```

Now neither Prometheus nor user can differentiate these two time series.

Prometheus provides only the API for deleting time series matching the given [series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors) - see [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#delete-series) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete every relevant timeseries then it should no longer be returned. If this is not the case, please file a bug.

Comment: I'm using this `https://prometheus.example.com/api/v1/series?match[]=my_label_job{exported_job="my_job",instance="localhost:9091",job="pushgateway"}` which comes back with a success message. `my_label_job` is still visible as an option in the drop down menu but returns no values. So it seems the timeseries is no longer returned but the actual label is visible in the dropdown menu on the graph page

Comment: Are there other timeseries with that name?

Comment: Not identical ones. What happened was I was testing with "my_label_job" and then wanted to change it to "my_label_job_new" so i created a new label. Now both of them appear in the drop down but I would just like "my_label_job_new" so I ran the above URL query (and tried via curl). Both succeeded in deleting something as the returned message showed but the original label still appears in the drop down.

Comment: I should add the old label returns `no data`. How can I check if all the timeseries are deleted, maybe I'm just deleting one instance of it via that URL?